# If And formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Not sure if this is workable, but I'm trying to put the below box into a IF formula. For example, Cell A1 would have the Age as of 12/31/2012 and Cell B1 would have the Years of Service as of 12/31/2012. Lets say A1 is 54 and B1 is 21, then I would want Cell C1 to say "A" for Group A. If A1 is 54 and B1 is 19 then I would want Cell C1 to say "B" for Group B. Is this something that can be accomplished easily?

Thank you!

Age as of 12/31/2012      Years of Service as of 12/31/2012                               Group
65 – 55                                          0.1 or more                                 A
54 – 50                                          20 or more                                  A
49 – 41                                          25 or more                                  A

54 – 50                                           19 – 0.1                                      B
49 – 45                                            24 – 15                                      B
44 – 36                                            24 – 20                                      B

49 – 45                                            14 or less                                  C
44 or less                                         19 or less                                  C

I'm just getting errors because my formula isn't correct.

Comment: This question is extremely unclear and chaotic. The logic of what you are trying to achieve is not explained. Also the code you have tried and want to get working is missing. Stackoverflow questions can NEVER be "can you do my work for me", but rather: "why doesn't my code work"  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking any further questions here and update your question to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a formula you can use in cell C1:

```
=IF(A1>=65,"A",IF(A1>=54,IF(B1>=20,"A","B"),IF(A1>=49,IF(B1>=25,"A","B"),IF(A1>=45,IF(B1>=15,"B","C"),IF(A1>=36,IF(B1>=20,"B","C"),"C")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your criteria:

Group A =

- (A1 >= 55 && A1 <= 65) && (B1 > 0.1) --OR--
- (A1 >= 50 && A1 < 55) && (B1 >= 20) --OR--
- (A1 >= 41 && A1 < 50) && (B1 >= 25)

Group B =

- (A1 >= 50 && A1 < 54) && (B1 >= 19) --OR--
- (A1 >= 45 && A1 < 50) && (B1 >= 15 && B1 < 25) --OR--
- (A1 >= 36 && A1 < 45) && (B1 >= 20 && B1 < 25)

Group C=

- (A1 >= 45 && A1 <50) && (B1 <= 14) --OR--
- (A1 < 45) && (B1 <=19)

If those are correct, then your formula should be:

```
=IF(OR(AND(A1>=55, A1<=65, B1>0.1), AND(A1>=50, A1<55, B1>=20), AND(A1>=41, A1<50, B1>=25)), "A", IF(OR(AND(A1>=50, A1<54, B1>=19), AND(A1>=45, A1<50, B1>=15, B1<25), AND(A1>=36, A1<45, B1>=20, B1<25)), "B", IF(OR(AND(A1>=45, A1<50, B1<=14), AND(A1>45, B1<=19)), "C", "Other")))
```

For debugging purposes, we can write it out like this:

```
=IF(
    OR(
        AND(A1>=55, A1<=65, B1>0.1), 
        AND(A1>=50, A1<55, B1>=20), 
        AND(A1>=41, A1<50, B1>=25)
    ), "A", 
    IF(
        OR(
            AND(A1>=50, A1<54, B1>=19), 
            AND(A1>=45, A1<50, B1>=15, B1<25), 
            AND(A1>=36, A1<45, B1>=20, B1<25)
        ), "B", 
        IF(
            OR(
                AND(A1>=45, A1<50, B1<=14), 
                AND(A1>45, B1<=19)
            ), "C", 
        "Other")
    )
)
```

Notes:

- This formula will return "Other" if none of those criteria are met.
- If your spreadsheet has headers, start this formula in "C1," copy down, then replace "C1" with the "Group" header. Otherwise, you'll end up with cell C2 looking at A1 and B1, etc. :)